# angular 2 ngFor and isotope don't work

Tags: jquery, angular, jquery-isotope

I use jQuery plug-in isotope. Plug-in to each element adds a different style depending on the location of the element. With ngFor it does not work. `ngAfterContentChecked()` don't solve the problem of connectivity Isotope.
Example: 
http://plnkr.co/edit/6VS4t6BMuujmhtzcPYWm?p=preview
What could be the reason?

Comment: I don't see your example working inside or outside the ngFor, if you click F12 on chrome you'll see you are getting a lot of errors, and I noticed you are bootstraping your app twice, one from main and in app again.

Answer (score 0):

I see several problems in your code:

- You call twice the `bootstrap` function. You should use it only once within your `main.ts` file
- You don't export your `AppComponent` component to be access from the `main.ts` module.

This way you don't have anymore, the following error: `Error: Token must be defined!`.

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: Thank you, fix bugs `Error: Token must be defined!`, but *ngFor all the same don't work

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess that if you're using *ngFor, your problem is that the isotope initialization is completed before the container items have been populated. If you're still having this problem, isotope has a method to call when items are dynamically added to the isotope container. See the documentation here: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/v1/docs/adding-items.html

My solution was to trigger an event when all of my isotope container contents had finished loading, and then a listener in the parent component called `container.isotope('insert', containerItems)`. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I simply resolved with a setTimeout() function

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
      setTimeout(() => {
        jQuery('.grid').isotope({
          itemSelector: '.grid-item',
          masonry: {
            columnWidth: 200
          }
        });
      }, 100);
  }
```

You can change the timeout value.